# Passing Maven Compiler Options From The Command-line

Tags: java, maven-2, command-line

I am setting up several projects on a continuous integration server, some of which I don't have access to change the source code to, The server is a linux box, I am running into a problem where maven encoding needs to be changed to UTF8 to be able to compile on the box. Since I don't have access to modify the pom file, I was wondering if I can pass the compiler options as a command-line param? The project uses maven compiler 2.0 and I tried passing -Denconding=UTF8 without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Maven property "project.build.sourceEncoding".

So something along the lines of
`mvn clean install -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8` should accomplish what you need.

This is equivalent of

```
<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

in your pom.xml.

Edit:  As a point of reference, there is the following link available [POM Element for Source File Encoding](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/POM+Element+for+Source+File+Encoding) showing the nuances between these properties for both Maven 2.0 and 3.0

Comment: This does not work. In the link you reference it says it is available for maven compiler plugin starting 2.1, as I said above, the pom uses 2.0

Comment: I will accept the answer because it doesn't look like there is a way to do it with old compiler plugin :(